# How to get body from axios put request?.(server side code)

Tags: node.js, express, axios, put

I want to get the data from axios put request so i can update some data in mongodb.
this is the javascript in client

```
const saveProduct = (url, name, price, type, image) => {
  axios.put(url,
  {name: name, price: price, type: type, image: image})
  .then((response) => response.data)
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

in server

```
router.put('/save/:pid', (req, res) => {
  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.pid, {$set: dataFromAxios}, function(err, product){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // send success message
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the body data from `req.body`.

Just make sure that you already have json body parser before you register all of your route

```js
app.use(express.json());
```